# psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user {user}

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out what is wrong.

I am attempting to connect to a local install of postgres 11 on ubuntu 19.

`sudo -u postgres psql` gives me full access to the psql shell as user postgres. I created a new user and db, granted permissions, set a password, edited the pg_hba.conf file, and restarted the server. I have also ensured that my password is not expired.

Now I expect `psql "host=localhost user=marcos port=5433 dbname=reddit sslmode=require"` to connect to my database, but I get a password error: "psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user". I know the password I typed is correct, so what is wrong?

Here are the relevant pg_hba.conf lines:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
# custom rules
host    all             marcos          all                     md5
```

Comment: What do you see in the PostgreSQL log file? It should say which `pg_hba.conf` line was used. If it is really a wrong password, you must have made a mistake with the password after all.

Comment: I see you are using port 5433. Do you have multiple installations of postgres ? `sudo -u postgres psql` use the default port of 5432, check that your pg_hba corresponds to the right install and that you have created the user on the right install too.

Comment: Oh. Well now I feel silly. I used `sudo -u postgres psql -p 5433' to connect to the correct cluster and saw that there were no users. There goes 4 hours of what could have been productive time. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

follow this step for ubuntu/linxs

-> sudo -u postgres psql

-> postgres=#

After that right

->postgres=# \password

Enter new password for user “postgres”:

Enter it again:

Now check, the new password is working successfully.

Comment: BTW, there is a problem with the custom user's authentication not with postgres user.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with your old password, try this:

```
ALTER ROLE marcos WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '<new_password>';
```

And then connect to your DB with this password.